# Is there any mysql function which is not allow such data which contain script-tag or html-tag?

Tags: php, mysql, validation

In my register form, if user disable javacript validation for registeration form and try to insert value `<script>alert("hacked")</script>` then this value is inserting to in my database table.
Can you please assist me how can I secure my application from that type problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi Barmar,
No, problem is that, If i removed javascript validation and simply insert the data(<script>alert("test")</script>) in database using post method. it goes to my datbase table and i don't want this

Answer (score 3):

When you display data that has been provided by the user, you should use `htmlentities()` to ensure that any HTML tags get display literally, rather than being rendered by the browser.

Comment: Thanks for your reply,

it is good to display data to the browser. I just want to stop the inserting such type data which contain script tag or html tag.

Comment: then you need to write a validation function in PHP that does the same thing as your Javascript validation. There's no general answer for this, since it depends on what you want to allow in different input fields.

Comment: okay,
So there any function which return Boolean value if data contains script or html tag?

Comment: Not that I know of. You could use `strip_tags` and compare the result with the original. If they're different, then the original must have contained a tag.

Comment: How are you doing it in Javascript? It doesn't have a function that does that.

Comment: I have just put jquery validation for that form.

Answer (score 0):

Well `mysql` have `REPLACE()` function for this.

But in your case you can use `strip_tags` which will escape all the `html` tags.

```
$name = strip_tags($_REQUEST['name']);
```

If you dont want any special character to be inserted

```
echo strip_tags(str_replace(array('"','/','(','*',':','=','^','#',';'),'',$name);
```

This will treat all the remaining as string.

For reference see [Manual](https://www.google.com.pk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCkQFjAA&url=http://www.php.net/strip_tags&ei=7-GWUoq4JYaI0AXavoHoDg&usg=AFQjCNG-kKnC40nyk78YGWARo8q8wapgGw&sig2=mar8fPMEJ4gWtVlYEb2TTA&bvm=bv.57155469,d.d2k)

Comment: thanks for the answer,

But using strip_tag just remove the tag only not whole data.
if $_REQUEST['name'] = "<script>alert("hacked")</script>"; then alert("hacked"); value goes to database and which i don't want.

Comment: it is good for alternative solution. but I don't want to that such type data insert in my table. :(

Comment: what do you want to insert  then

Comment: If user insert simple text data in input box then it simply should go to database and if user insert script and html tag  for input box which shouldn't.